# Eigenvector Proof $(I+A)^{-1}$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that the eigenvectors of the $n \times n$ matrix **A** are also eigenvectors of the matrix $$M = (I+A)^{-1} $$ Where **I** is the $n \times n$ unit matrix. Determine the eigenvalues.

My Work:

$$Mx=(I+A)^{-1}x = ???$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if you have
$$
Ax=\lambda x
$$
then what do you get when you add $x$ to both sides?
$$
(I+A)x = (1+\lambda)x
$$
Now do a bit of matrix algebra to get $(I+A)^{-1}$ on the right and $1+\lambda$ on the left.

(Alternative way to think of it - if $(I+A)^{-1}x = \Lambda x$, then how can you rearrange this to get $Ax$ on its own?)

Comment: $$x= (\lambda+1)(I+A)^{-1}x \implies (I+A)^{-1}x= (\lambda+1)^{-1}x$$ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue for the eivenvector $x$.

Your work, with a minor addition:

$$(I+A)^{-1}x=\lambda x\implies x=(I+A)\lambda x $$

By expanding and reorganizing, you will see $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$, but the eigenvalue that appears might be something you didn't guess.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=\lambda x$, then $(A+I)x = (\lambda + 1)x$. If $A+I$ is invertible, then one can multiply with $(A+I)^{-1}$ on both sides to get $(A+I)^{-1}x = \frac{1}{\lambda + 1}x$